# Moving out from SendGrid link branding

Tags: dns, sendgrid

We had an account on SendGrid, and we used link branding with custom subdomain (emails.example.com). We stopped using SendGrid and switched to other email service, but we still want to support our old emails. Right now, old email links are working fine, as we still have DNS set to redirect from emails.example.com to sendgrid.net, and SendGrid still redirects to correct urls, but we are completely dependent on SendGrid right now, and we don't know if at some point in future SendGrid will simply stop redirecting this links.

So, the question is how we can redirect old email links to point to our website?

I think it's impossible, as link branding feature replaced not just domain, but also the path from the links.

Maybe someone from SendGrid will have some answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

I've checked internally and as long as you keep the DNS in place, the redirects will continue to work.

Comment: And if we completely close/delete account on SendGrid, redirects will still work? Can we somehow export this data, as I guess you store original url, and replaced url? If we can get that, then we will be able to match those in our app, and redirect correctly inside the app. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to export this data. If I were you, I would contact [SendGrid support](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us) with these questions as they are better placed to answer them.

Comment: Yea, I already contacted SendGrid support, and the answer is NO, we can't export the data.